Change the position of caption in gb4e
I want to move a caption containing metalinguistic information so that it aligns to the right.
This is my current tex document
%okegas yuk bisa yuk

\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\ExpandArgs{c}\newcommand{new@fontshape}{anything}

\usepackage[russian,indonesian]{babel}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\primebars
\let\emptyset\varnothing

\geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=20mm,
 top=20mm,
 }

\newcommand{\?}[1]{\foreignlanguage{russian}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{exe}

\let\eachwordone=\it

\noautomath
\setlength{\glossglue}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}
\renewcommand{\eachwordtwo}{\rule[-10pt]{0pt}{0pt}}

\ex
\gll \?{Но} \?{есть} \?{и} \?{особые} \?{приложения} \?{для} \?{гомосексуалистов}, \?{любителей} \?{садо-мазо} \?{и} \?{даже} \?{группового} \?{секса} \\
no est' i osobye priloženija dlja gomoseksualistov\textsc{.pen}, ljubitelej\textsc{.pen}, sado-mazo\textsc{.pen}, i daže gruppovogo seksa \\
\trans “{\bf Tetapi ada aplikasi khusus untuk para homoseksual, pecinta sadomasokisme dan bahkan seks berkelompok.}” (\textsc{pen} = Strategi penamaan)

\end{exe}

\end{document}

Which produce this typeset:

Next to the translation, there is a caption (the bracketed sentences) containing metalinguistic information. I want to move it so that it:

Lies above the translation line
Lies under the gloss
Aligns to the right

Like so:

How can I improve my tex document?

If you load the cgloss package (available from here but sadly not on CTAN), you can add other information to the main line in the example just by adding an \hfill at the end of the gloss line. This is mainly designed for adding language names to examples, which is why it aligns with the first line of the example, not the gloss line. To align it with the gloss, we need to add some vertical space, which I've done here by putting the annotation into a tabular environment. I've wrapped the whole thing into a command \annote which can then be added to any example.
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\ExpandArgs{c}\newcommand{new@fontshape}{anything}

\usepackage[russian,indonesian]{babel}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{gb4e,cgloss}
\primebars
\let\emptyset\varnothing

\geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=20mm,
 top=20mm,
 }

\newcommand{\?}[1]{\foreignlanguage{russian}{#1}}
\newcommand{\annote}[1]{\hfill\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}\\#1\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}

\begin{exe}

\let\eachwordone=\it

\noautomath
\setlength{\glossglue}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}
\renewcommand{\eachwordtwo}{\rule[-10pt]{0pt}{0pt}}

\ex
\gll \?{Но} \?{есть} \?{и} \?{особые} \?{приложения} \?{для} \?{гомосексуалистов}, \?{любителей} \?{садо-мазо} \?{и} \?{даже} \?{группового} \?{секса} {} \\
no est' i osobye priloženija dlja gomoseksualistov\textsc{.pen}, ljubitelej\textsc{.pen}, sado-mazo\textsc{.pen}, i daže gruppovogo seksa \\\annote{(\textsc{pen} = Strategi penamaan)}
\trans “{\bf Tetapi ada aplikasi khusus untuk para homoseksual, pecinta sadomasokisme dan bahkan seks berkelompok.}” 

\end{exe}

\end{document}



This worked, thank you!
